# Как импортировать собственный класс в jinja?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, jinja2

Я пытаюсь проверить принадлежность объекта к определенному классу, но мне выдается ошибка:

[image: Ошибка]

**Код:**

history.html

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block title %}История{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1 class="text-center">История</h1>
    {% if transactions %}
        {% for el in transactions %}
            {% if isinstance(IncomeTransaction, el) %}
                <div class="alert alert-warning">
                    <h3>Транзакция дохода</h3>
                    <p>Дата: {{ el.date }}</p>
                    <p>Сумма: {{el.amount}}</p>
                    <p>Комментарий: {{ el.commentary }}</p>
                    <p>Счет: {{ el.account.name }}</p>
                    <p>Категория дохода: {{ el.income_category.name }}</p>
                </div>
            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <p class="text-center">У вас еще не было транзакций</p>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не использовал jinja, если брать просто шаблоны джанго, то можно просто использовать
`{% if el.__class__.__name__ == 'IncomeTransaction' %}`
правда такой вариант не будет отрабатывать потомков класса, что является минусом

либо писать кастомный [template Tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters)